# in a jqgrid editform, i need to restrict checkbox selection to only one at a time

Tags: jqgrid

i have a jqgrid editform with three checkboxes.  I need the checkboxes to function like typical html Radio buttons that let a user select ONLY ONE of a limited number of choices.

Unfortunately, jqgrid does not offer radio button editypes.

I know that i can setup an event to deselect all other checkboxes in the editform.  Is this the only way to do it in jqgrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the `click` event to any from the checkboxes and in the event handler to uncheck all other chechboxes in the form if the current checkbox will be checked.

Comment: Thanks... As i suspected, setting up an event is the only way.

Comment: @NelsonM: You are welcome! You can set `click` handler either using [dataEvents](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) for every column or make binding directly during the form initialization inside of `afterShowForm` or `beforeShowForm` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events)).

Comment: I will most likely use dataEvents for each checkbox - thanks again.